# What will my Apps URL be in google play when i publish it?

Tags: android, google-play

In my app i will be including a feature where the user uploads information to facebook and asks for help. As part of that upload i want include a link to the google play store so if others see it on their phones etc they may like to download. As part of that i will need to know the google play link before I publish it on Google Play. Is there a predetermined formula for getting the link. I.e play.google.com/store/com.mypackagename.html ?

or will i have to direct it to a webpage of mine that after its been published i use a redirect the user to the google play page?

Answer (score 38):

Currently, it will be

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourpackagename
```

Where `com.yourpackagename` is your package as defined in your `AndroidMainfest.xml`

Comment: @Xeo for more information http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

Comment: No matter how much googling i couldnt find that page on google. Thank you all.

Comment: I think current actual page of documentation for that is https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html

Answer (score 5):

It will be

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourpackagename
```

For example if package name of your app is `org.kidinov.unixadmin` url will be

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.unixadmin
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application url will be like this format:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`

YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME should be as it in your menifest.xml file.

e.g; `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinterest` **where com.pinterest is a package name.**

hoep it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application URL will be

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=+YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME
```

package name is the unique identifier of your app